# Getting "configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs" when trying to use LinuxBrew on RPi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, homebrew, raspbian, linuxbrew

I’m trying to install node on a Raspberry Pi

I’m connected to it’s command line using screen

I installed LinuxBrew successfully, however whenever I try and install a package

If I do:

```
brew install node (--host)
```

I get:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/tmp/pkg-config20160301-6502-vg0e9w/pkg-config-0.29':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
Error: Unable to locate the system's glibc
```

When I try and install glibc with: `brew install glibc --with-binutils --with-linux-headers`
 I get the exact same error.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

P.S: It's a Model 2 B Pi

aTdHvAaNnKcSe